# Not Displaying Normal Xcode View

Tags: xcode

First, the links are to screen shots of my "problem". Stackoverflow would not let me post images b/c I don't have at least a 10 reputation.

I am not sure what I did.

Shut down my computer, I think there was an OS X update pending that installed. When I went back to my Xcode project it presented the normal screen

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzpqJUv4HwzCbldESkRnZHR0Tk0/edit

But then when I went to open it up the following screen w/o the editor or any of the normal layout opened up.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzpqJUv4HwzCZ2ZJOF9fSzAybUk/edit

I tried tinkering with the layout and view screens, but no real help. Not sure what happened. Any help would be most appreciated. Basically, it seems like I am missing the editor and utilities panes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You see that little button with the left arrow and two vertical lines at the right upper end of the "Groups and files" view? Click and drag it left, see it this can help.

Comment: No help. Held down and dragged and nothing happened. Basically, I want to get the Editor and Utility panes. For some reason this has turned into a little bit of a complex endeavor.

Comment: Did you tried the 'View' menu then? There are sub categories for Standard Editor and etc? See if this will help.

Comment: Not sure where you want me to go in the view menu. But I didn't find a/t.